# AWS DMS Replication Instances on different Availability Zones Connection Issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-migration, aws-dms

I am facing an issue with AWS DMS Replication Instance - it is not working on a specific AZ.

**Below explains the scenario and setup:**

**AWS Account #1**

- MySQL RDS (Multi-AZ)

**AWS Account #2**

- DMS Replication Instance (on Availability Zone - A)
- DMS Replication Instance (on Availability Zone - B)
- EC2 Instance (on Availability Zone A)

Both AWS accounts are connected fine with a Transit Gateway between them.

The RDS has a Security Group attached to allow communication from Account #2 to Account #1.

When connecting to the RDS through the EC2 instance, it works fine. When testing the DMS endpoint using the Replication Instance (AZ-A) it does not work, but when testing the DMS endpoint using the Replication Instance (AZ-B) it works fine.

I checked every single thing, from Security Groups, to Network ACLs, to Transit Gateways - all communication (inbound rules) are fine but still not sure what's the issue.

Any help or tips on the solution would be great.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix!

There was a missing route table entry pointing to the Transit Gateway!

The following entry worked for me:

**Destination = 0.0.0.0/0**

**Target = {PUT YOUR TRANSIT GATEWAY ID HERE, e.g. tgw-xxxxx}**